# how to serve static file in node.js?

Tags: upload, static, express

in my app user can upload images to server,and i put the uploaded file in upload folder like this

- public
- upload

but when i serve the

```
<img src='upload/image.jpg'/>
```

there is a 404 error.

i use express and use the

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

does it mean i have to put all the uploaded in the public folder, what if there is so many images that the hard drive can not hold, can't i put the rest in a another server?

Answer (score 2):

**No you don't have to put all uploaded files to public folder.**

Express allows to configure multiple middle-ware so you can add one more middle-ware to serve static content from the desired directory.

If you want directory to be specified in Url path then you can use directory mount feature like this !!

```
app.use('/upload',express.static(__dirname + '/upload'));
```

**Ofcouse you can use other server to store uploaded files and you can retrieve those file by proxing request to it.**

```
app.get('/upload/:fileName',function(req,res) {

     var options = {
        port: 80,
        method : 'GET',
        hostname : "localhost",
        path : "/upload/" + req.params.fileName
     };

    var req = http.request(options,function(response) {     
        response.pipe(res);
    });

    req.on('error',function(err) {
        res.statusCode = 404;
        res.end("Error : file not found");
    }); 

    req.end();
});
```

This code will work not only when uploaded files are stored in the original server but also if you have files on some other server too !!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the images in ./public/upload

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

```
<img src='/upload/image.jpg'/>
```

Notice the slash before upload. It could be that the problem isn't where you save the files, but rather how you're referencing them. If the page with the `img` tag isn't in your root directory, then the relative url `upload/image.jpg` won't work. You need to use `/upload/image.jpg`.

Answer (score 0):

If you

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

and `./public` contains:

```
/img.png
/img2.png
/logo.png
```

`yourapp.com/img.png` will be img.png.

If you want `yourapp.com/img.png` to be a 404 and `yourapp.com/public/img.png` to be img.png, you need to replace

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```

with

```
app.use("/public",express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
```